# Understanding how to solve a system of equations with a constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Consider 
$$
\Phi(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+...+\beta_KX_k}{\sigma})
$$
where

- $\Phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a known function
- $\beta_1, ..., \beta_K, \sigma$ are unknown real-valued parameters with $\sigma>0$
- $X_2, ..., X_K$ are known real numbers

It can be seen that
$$ (\star) \hspace{1cm}
\Phi(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+...+\beta_KX_k}{\sigma})=
\Phi(\frac{\tilde{\beta}_1+\tilde{\beta}_2X_2+\tilde{\beta}_3X_3+...+\tilde{\beta}_KX_k}{\tilde{ \sigma}})
$$
where
$\tilde{\beta}_k\equiv\alpha \beta_k$ $\forall k=1,..., K$ and $\tilde{\sigma}\equiv \alpha \sigma$ for any $\alpha>0$

Suppose that now I impose the constraint $\beta_1^2+ \beta_2^2+...+\beta_K^2=1$

Question: can we still find an $\alpha>0$ such that $(\star)$ holds together with $\tilde{\beta}_1^2+ \tilde{\beta}_2^2+...+\tilde{\beta}_K^2=1$?

My intuition is that we can't. Can you help me to formally show this? Do we need to use some conditions on $\Phi$, such that continuity or strict monotonicity?

Comment: I don’t understand your problems, because equality $(\star)$ holds for any choice of $\alpha$, $\sigma$, $\beta$’s and $X$’s, because  the argument of the function from the left hand side equals the argument of the function from the left hand side, right?

Comment: Equality $(\star)$ holds for any choice of $\alpha, \sigma,\beta$.

Comment: Suppose now I instead suppose the following: 
$$
\Phi(\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+...+\beta_KX_k}{\sigma})
$$
where

 $\Phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a known function;
$\beta_1, ..., \beta_K, \sigma$ are unknown real-valued parameters with $\sigma>0$ AND $\beta_1^2+...+\beta^2_K=1$;
$X_2, ..., X_K$ are known real numbers

Comment: My question is: does $(\star)$ still hold?

Comment: @STF Yes, it still holds. I might still be misunderstanding but those expression are equal for all reals, given your definitions of $\alpha$ and  $ \sigma$ (given the obvious $\sigma \neq 0$) really there is no constraint on the $\beta$'s where it would not hold. There are also no values for $\alpha$ where it would not hold. This leads me to believe I still misunderstand your question. What does the function have to do with it? The expressions where the function is evaluated are per definition equal so the function really doesn't matter.

Comment: @zen: thanks for your comment; I am trying to translate a question in statistics (why identification of parameters in a Probit model is up to a scale) to a math problem and I am struggling with it, apologies for the confusion. What I want is also that $\tilde{\beta}_1^2+ \tilde{\beta}_2^2+...+\tilde{\beta}_K^2=1$. Is there any $\alpha$ preserving $(\star)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the updated question is that yes such an $\alpha$ exists and is equal to one. This is trivial to see since then $\tilde{\beta}_K=\beta_{K} \forall K$. so if one restriction holds the other holds as well and it is trivial that * holds.
There is no ther solution since if $\beta_1^2+ \beta_2^2+...+\beta_K^2=1$ then $\tilde{\beta}_1^2+ \tilde{\beta}_2^2+...+\tilde{\beta}_K^2=(\alpha\beta_1)^2+ (\alpha\beta_2)^2+...+(\alpha\beta_K)^2=\alpha^2\beta_1^2+ \alpha^2\beta_2^2+...+\alpha^2\beta_K^2=\alpha^2(\beta_1^2+ \beta_2^2+...+\beta_K^2)=\alpha^2(1)=\alpha^2$

so if both constraints are true and $\alpha>0$ then this implies $\alpha=1$
This is indepedent of the function $\Phi$

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. As all "tilted" variables have the factor $\alpha$, it cancels out in the fraction and the property is valid for any $\alpha$, regardless any constraint on the $\beta$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are ofcourse right witch I also mentioned in a comment. However OP has edited the question so that there are  two constraints. These two constraints imply that $\alpha=1$ is the only answer. You are right that (*) does not imply anything about $\alpha$.

Comment: You are right, I get it now. (Though there is a single constraint, not two.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust $ \beta_1^2+ \beta_2^2+...+\beta_K^2=1$ is one and the other is $\tilde{\beta}_1^2+ \tilde{\beta}_2^2+...+\tilde{\beta}_K^2=1$

Comment: Ok, sorry. So formulated, the question is so unexpected. (Obviously $\beta=\tilde\beta$).